# proof by contradiction v.s. contrapositive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I had to show proof by contradiction for if $3x+2$ is odd, then $x$ is odd...

my contradiction was

Assume not, $3x+2$ is odd, and $x$ is even
if $x = 2k$ by the def of $x = 2k$.

$2x+2 = 2(2k) +2$, there is a contradiction

how is this written in contrapositive form?

Comment: Do you want proof of  if 3x+2 is odd, then x is odd...??

Comment: Contrapositive means: if $x$ is even then $3x+2$ if even.

Comment: yeah, i know its not p = to not q, but i'm not sure how to state it in words perse

Comment: Suppose that $x$ is even, $x=2k$. So $3x+2=3.2k+2=2(3k+1)$ wich is even.

Comment: Notice you assumed the conclusion is false and proved that this assumption implies that the hypothesis is false. This is *precisely* a proof by contraposition, and would be (in my opinion) better stated as such from the beginning. You might start your proof: "We instead prove the contrapositive: If $x$ is even, then $3x + 2$ is even."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrapositive means: If $x$ is even, then $3x+2$ is even.

Suppose that $x$ is even, $x=2k$.

So $3x+2=3(2k)+2=2(3k+1)$ which is even.